# Hive Partition recovery

Tags: hive, hdfs, hql, hadoop-partitioning

How to recover partitions in easy fashion. Here is the scenario :

> 1. Have 'n' partitions on existing external table 't'
> 2. Dropped table 't'
> 3. Recreated table 't' ***// Note : same table but with excluding some column***
> 4. How to recover the 'n' partitions that existed for table 't' in step #1 ?

I can manually alter table to add 'n' partition by writing some script. But that's very tedious. Is there something built-in to recover these partitions ?

Answer (score 5):

When the partitions directories still exist in the HDFS, simply run this command:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

It adds the partitions definitions to the metastore based on what exists in the table directory.

Comment: I didnt try it with custom Serde, but i think Serdes does not affect this command, it should work fine !

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, The Serde should not have any issues. But from what the documentation mentions is that the partitions can be recovered if only the parition format is 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Not sure how to use for custom partition format ? in mycase, I have something like yyyymmdd.

Comment: The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)) didnt put any limit for that, but by logic there is one thing to care about, is the partition format should be 'key=value', eg. date=160528 and no problem if it has hyphens or not.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata is not saved in the trash and is removed permanently; you will not be able to restore the metadata of dropped tables, partitions, etc. Reference: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_hive_trash.html